# Js не подставляются значения из input в action формы

Tags: javascript, laravel

Есть простой `js` скрипт который подставляет ссылку из ***чекбоксов***. С обычной ссылкой все работает, но в `action` формы почему-то не подставляет. Спасибо!

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches('[data-url]')) {
    target.href = evt.target.dataset.url
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group radio-group">
      <p class="label">Тип вашего профиля:</p>
      <div class="custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="yes" class="" name="user_type" value="donator" data-url="{{ route('register') }}" checked>
        <label for="yes"> <span class="circle"></span>Пользователь</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="no" class="" name="user_type" value="volounteer" data-url="{{ route('vol.register') }}">
        <label for="no"><span class="circle"></span>Индивидуальный волонтер</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="no1" class="" name="user_type" value="organisation" data-url="{{ route('vol.register') }}">
        <label for="no1"><span class="circle"></span>Благотворительная организация</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="//example.com" id="target">some link</a>
```

Comment: `var data = this.dataset.url; if( data ){ action.href = data; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, извиняюсь. Уже сам поправил.

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches('[data-url]')) {
    action.href = evt.target.dataset.url
  }
})
```